# Keep the filterValue in p:column

Tags: primefaces

I would like to keep the filterValue user type in as long as user did not clear the filter text. I have bind the filterValue of p:column to a session variable. But I kept getting null. Like this, user does not have to type in the filter one more time when they go back to the listing page.

I am using PF 3.5.

```
<p:column id="mm1001_column_lendborrow" width="60"
    sortBy="#{varlistOfMoneyMarket.borrow_lend_dn}"
    filterBy="#{varlistOfMoneyMarket.borrow_lend_dn}"
    filterMatchMode="contains" resizable="true"
    filterStyle="width:50px"
    style="text-align: left; font-weight : 400"
    headerText="#{msg.mm1001_gridheader_lend_borrow}"
    filterValue="#{pc_Mm1001.w_mmdeal.lb_filter}">
    <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridText_px"
        id="mm1001_gridoutput_lend_borrow"
        value="#{varlistOfMoneyMarket.borrow_lend_dn}"></h:outputText>
    <f:attribute value="60" name="width" />
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

filterValue attribute is used only to initialize filter, also only getter method is invoked.
It's not updated when you change it.

Have a look at this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5361)